# Real Analysis Qualifying Exam Sample Question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Studying for the RA Quals, when my best friend and I came across this problem in Chapter 4 of Wheeler's, "Measure and Integral an Introduction to Real Analysis," #15 pg 62. We're just curious if anybody could/would tell us how to approach it.**

---

Let $\{f_{k}\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on a measurable $E$ with $|E|<+\infty$. If $|f_{k}(x)|\leq M_{x}<+\infty$ for all $k$ for each $x\in E$, show that given $\epsilon >0$, there is a closed $F\subset E$ and a finite $M$ such that $|E-F|<\epsilon$ and $|f_{k}(x)|\leq M$ for all $k$ and all $x\in F$.

---

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What definitions and theorems do you have to work with?

Comment: Hint: consider the sets $\{x \in E : M_x \leq n\}$ as $n$ ranges over the positive integers. These sets cover $E$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume $M_x = \sup_k \lvert f_k(x) \rvert$. For each positive integer $n$, let $S_n = \{x \in E : M_x \leq n\}$. Since each $M_x$ is finite, $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} S_n = E$. Also, for each $n$, we have that
$$S_n = \bigcap_k \{x \in E : \lvert f_k(x) \rvert \leq n\}$$
is measurable (since it is a countable intersection of measurable sets). Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since the sequence $\lvert \bigcup_{n=1}^m S_n \rvert$ increases monotonically to $\lvert E \rvert < \infty$, there is some $M > 0$ such that $F_0 := \bigcup_{n=1}^M S_n$ satisfies $\lvert E - F_0 \rvert < \varepsilon/2$, and moreover $\lvert f_k(x) \rvert \leq M$ for all $k$ and all $x \in F_0$.

The only issue is that $F_0$ might not be closed! Here, we use the regularity of the Lebesgue measure to produce an open set $O \supseteq F_0$ and a closed set $F \subseteq F_0$ such that $\lvert O - F \rvert < \varepsilon/2$. Now, since $F$ is a subset of $F_0$, we have
$$\lvert E - F \rvert = \lvert E - F_0 \rvert + \lvert F_0 - F\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \lvert O - F \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$
and $\lvert f_k(x) \rvert \leq M$ for all $k$ and all $x \in F$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This is pretty much what we were thinking. We just weren't sure about our approach.